# Exact triangle in derived categories

Tags: homological-algebra, derived-categories

Suppose there is an exact triangle $A \to B \to C \to A[1]$ in $D^b(\mathcal A)$, where $A,B,C$ are concentrated in degree $0$. Does it follows that there is a short exact sequence $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$ in $\mathcal A$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An exact triangle $A\to B\to C\to A[1]$ in the derived category gives you the cohomology long exact sequence $$\cdots\to H^0(A)\to H^0(B)\to H^0(C)\to H^1(A)\to \cdots.$$

Since $A,\ B,\ C$ are concentrated in degree zero, they are equal to their zeroth cohomology. This gives you the exact sequence $0\to A\to B\to C\to 0.$

Comment: of course, I was being stupid. Thank you !